# Pygame: AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'display'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame-surface

**Code:**

```py
import pygame, sys, os 
from pygame.locals import *
red = (255,0,0)
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither.eat - The Snake Game')
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
screen.fill(red)
screen.display.set_caption("Snake")
pygame.display.flip()
while True:
    print("Slither.eat - The Snake Game!")
    pass
```

When I execute the program, it gives the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\ELCOT\Python38\pygame-master\pygame-master\001 PyGame Hello World.py", line 13, in <module>
    screen.display.set_caption("Snake")
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'display'
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line. You can remove it and your code will run.

```py
screen.display.set_caption("Snake")
```

**Explanation:**

There's a difference between `Surface` and `display` in pygame. You can set a caption for a `display` which you are doing in this line:

```py
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither.eat - The Snake Game')
```

Answer (score 0):

which title do you want? 'Slither.eat - The Snake Game' or Snake
if you want Slither.eat - The Snake Game then type in:

```
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither.eat - The Snake Game')
```

however, if you want the snake game as title type in:

```
pygame.display.set_caption(The Snake Game)
```

hope it helps, even though its been 2 years :^